# radclient:: Failed to find IP address

Tags: radius, freeradius

I installed freeradius on CentOS 6.6 and I have configured the files /etc/raddb/clients and /etc/raddb/users. 
I am trying to test the server by this command :

```
radtest Aicha passme 127.0.0.1 100 testing123
```

This is the result :

```
radclient:: Failed to find IP address for Host-002
radclient: Nothing to send.
[root@Host-002 ~]#
```

This is my file /etc/hosts :

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

Declaration of the user Aicha in /etc/raddb/users:

```
"Aicha"     Cleartext-Password := "passme"
        Framed-IP-Address = 192.168.1.65,
        Reply-Message = "Hello, %{User-Name}"
```

How to fix that ? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

radtest is trying to resolve the IP address of your host so it can use it for the value of NAS-IP-Address.

Add an entry for `Host-002` in `/etc/hosts`, mapping it either to a loopback IP or the IP you want to use for NAS-IP-Address.

Answer (score 1):

asname
              If  present,  this  will be resolved to an IP address and added to the request packet as the
              NAS-IP-Address attribute. If you don’t specify it, the local hostname of the system will  be
              used.

## radtest testing password 192.168.1.90 1 testing123 nasname "192.168.1.90"

Comment: please fix the formatting of your answer ...

Comment: It looks like something has been cut off from the beginning of your answer. As it looks like you're quoting from the `radtest(1)` man page, you might want to say so. Just a simple "From `radtest(1)`:" at the beginning of your answer would be nice.